# C# XElement updating a node

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm just wondering what is the best way to update an existing node in XML without updating the entire object? Let's see..

In my XML document I have the following:

```
   <DirUser override="always">
      <UserDirectory header="Users" enabled="false" /> 
      <StaffDirectory header="Staff" enabled="true" />
          <Phones>
             <Field>Number</Field>
             <Field>Mob</Field>
           </Phones>
      </StaffDirectory>
   </DirUser>
```

In my C# code I have the following:

```
public void UpdateContact(XElement element)
{

}
```

I can call this method using the XElement through the following:

```
XElement contacts = XElement.Load("C:\\Path\\");
```

I'm confused to whether or not I would have to parse the XML again and what would the most efficient way be to change just the "visible="?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please define 'best'.

Answer (score 1):

XElement is like a tree structure containing other XElements/Nodes etc.
If you really want to pass the XElement that you get from Load you would have to select the correct XElement in your UpdateMethod

```
public void UpdateMethod(XElement element)
{
  XElement toUpdate = element.Descendants("ElementName").First();
  toUpdate.SetAttributeValue("AttributeName", "AttributeValue");
}
```

But you could also select the user XElement before and pass the user to the Method.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I have tried to add the `XElement user = element.Element("user");` I get the NULL exception.. I don't think it can find the "user" inside the XML - Should I parse it somewhere?

Comment: I see that in your example the closing "/" is missing for user. Maybe this is the problem? <user header="heading1" visible="true" />

Comment: Hey - No this was not the issue. When I pass in the value "element" it seems fine. I think there is a problem choosing the "user" because there are other nodes within it??

Comment: If there are more user in it, Element("user") provides you the first one. Maybe you can update your question to see the xml File in better detail. For example if user is not a child node of your Root Element and deeper inside your xml structure you can use Descendants("user").First()

Comment: Hey - I updated my post and I just need to `<UserDirectory header="Users" enabled="false" /> ` access this one for now.. There shouldn't be a problem accessing this should there?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs by 100%.

1. In case you need **only to set `visible` to true**, the code is just enough.
2. In case you need to present a user the possibility to change this XML code, or to import XML code to your application, or to any other thing which **requires** some work with XML code - you can use parsing.